# svn Error validating server certificate

Tags: svn, ssl-certificate

If I use any `svn` command communicating with the remote server I get the following error:

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://...':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: ...
 - Valid: from Wed, 01 Sep 2010 08:25:36 GMT until Thu, 06 Oct 2011 08:25:36 GMT
 - Issuer: ...
 - Fingerprint: ...
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
```

If I hit permanently I can run the command properly. But on the next `svn` command I get the same question and have to confirm again! Why doesn't `svn` save my choice permanently? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you hit permanently then svn does cache the certifcate information in the same place where it stores your username/password information. And it won't ask you next time to confirm the certificate until its cached.

Comment: but svn asks me the same stuff again! so it does not cache it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Search for the folder named "svn.ssl.server" (it exists for windows and *NIX servers) and delete it.  You may be asked one more time to save the key but then it should stop asking after that point.

Answer (score 47):

Fix (for Unix):

`svn.ssl.server` is on `~/.subversion/auth`

- Change Owner recursively on `~/.subversion/auth` or delete:
  delete - `~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server`
  owner  - `chown -R $USER ~/.subversion/auth`
- Open the command prompt and run `svn list https:...`
- Accept certficate permanently by entering `p`.

Have Fun !

Comment: Note that if you have a remote mounted drive it's possible that it can look like you're the owner of the file, if the remote system has the same username. This will prevent the above from working until you log in to the remote box itself. Well it fooled me for a while, hope it helps someone else.

Comment: what does "..." in 'svn list https:..." mean? the actual repo url?

Comment: I tried with the repository url, but still can't do svn up afterwards: the error validating message still popped up.

Comment: I have followed above instructions step by step and it worked on Mac OSX El Capitan. Yes, galactica. He means repository URL by "svn list https:...".

Comment: this thing works for university svn repositories! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 30):

Fix (for Windows):

- Delete `C:\Users\"USERNAME"\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server`
- Open the command prompt and run `svn list https:...`
- Accept certficate permanently by entering `p`.

Comment: This also solved, the same problem using svnkit in eclipse

Answer (score 9):

Probably not suitable for all users but is okay for me and worked:

I edited in the ~/.subversion/servers the following line:

```
[global]
ssl-trust-default-ca = no
```

to

```
[global]
ssl-trust-default-ca = yes
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution for SSL Certificate Error Message on SVNX**

> For Windows User:

1. Open the command prompt and run **svn list https://Your-Link-Goes-Here/**
2. List item Accept certificate permanently by entering **p**

> For Mac User:

1. Open the Terminal and Execute this command **svn list https://Your-Link-Goes-Here/**
2. Accept the Certificate Permanently by entering **p**

> **Note:** For Mac Users make sure your Certificate is already added in Keychain Access

Hope this Helps Someone.

Comment: @Umair are you a Mac or Windows User?

Comment: windows , particularly w7

Answer (score 5):

Doing `chmod 644 ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/*` 
is simplest for unix users and is best if you connect to multiple servers.

Comment: i'm a unix user and verified that this trick didn't work for me. BTW, I have two files under ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/, (using OpenSSH_5.3p1 on CentOS)

Answer (score 3):

SVN is smart enough to infer that you didn't actually bother verifying that the fingerprint matches.

Ahem.

But in all seriousness, https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Subversion#ServerCertificateVerificationFailed notes that you should open the project url in a trusted browser to check you're not being MITM'ed (should work for non-sourceforge too), e.g. you can try checking that you get the same fingerprint through [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/).

Answer (score 3):

`chmod -R 775 ~/.subversion/auth` may also be needed.