# Impossible to commit changes to SVN from Android Studio

Tags: svn, ssl, android-studio, credentials

I'm trying to commit some changes to my `svn`, using `Android Studio` but I can't. That worked, but suddenly stopped do it.

At first the problem said something like:

> MKACTIVITY forbidden 403.

I removed the folder `svn.ssl.server` as I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115170/svn-error-validating-server-certificate) and clean de auth cache from settings without results. but the problem changed,

> Now a window ask for my credentials permanently, and never store it. When I  press cancel I can see a error log with `code E230001` saying that the ssl certifcate is untrusted.

(I'm sure the credentials are correct)

Please, I really need help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well.. I almost have fixed the problem doing a new checkout, in one project that works, but in  other project I get the first mistake on more time "MKACTIVITY forbidden 403."

Any ideas?
Thanks